# Inserting a set of input fields and button from data-id of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a form that shows itself after I clicked on a button, and the save button would allow me to save the input values into an object.

What would be a more efficient way to write this function if I need to have 9 more of the same button with different data-id(e.g. data-id="2" and so on), without having to duplicate the function into *saveConditionOne*,*saveConditionTwo*,*saveConditionThree*.

```js
const patient = {}

// Save conditions to object
function saveConditions() {
  const missing = document.getElementById('missingVal').value
  const movement = document.getElementById('movementVal').value
  const tilt = document.getElementById('tiltVal').value

  patient.one = {
    missing: missing,
    movement: movement,
    tilt: tilt
  }
  console.log(patient)
}
```

```html
<button data-id="1" id="showForm" class="btn">1</button>

<div id="conditionSelect">
  <h5>Form</h5>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="">Missing Tooth</label>
    <input type="text" id="missingVal">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="">Movement</label>
    <input type="text" id="movementVal">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="">Tilt</label>
    <input type="text" id="tiltVal">
  </div>
  <button id="saveCondition" onclick="saveConditions()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
```

**Now**

```
{
  "one": {
    "missing": "tooth",
    "movement": "1mm",
    "tilt": "10deg"
  }
}
```

**Expected**

```
{
  "one": {
    "missing": "tooth",
    "movement": "1mm",
    "tilt": "10deg"
  },
  "two": {
    "missing": "tooth",
    "movement": "1mm",
    "tilt": "10deg"
  },
  "three": {
    "missing": "tooth",
    "movement": "1mm",
    "tilt": "10deg"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it just the button that there may be nine of, or the structure the function fills in as well?

Comment: You could just use a parameter like `saveConditions(index)`, but share your full code of the problem.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder right now there are a total of 10 buttons in the HTML, I'd like to find a way to have just 1 instead of 10 x 3 sets of the same input fields in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use an object for `patient` (or at least, not for this part of the patient information), I'd use an array. Then you simply push the data onto the array:

```
patient.push({
  missing: missing,
  movement: movement,
  tilt: tilt
});
```

...or if you make this a property on the `patient` object (perhaps there is other, patient-wide information):

```
patient.entries.push({
  missing: missing,
  movement: movement,
  tilt: tilt
});
```

Live Example:

```js
const patient = {
  entries: []
}

// Save conditions to object
function saveConditions() {
  const missing = document.getElementById('missingVal').value
  const movement = document.getElementById('movementVal').value
  const tilt = document.getElementById('tiltVal').value

  patient.entries.push({
    missing: missing,
    movement: movement,
    tilt: tilt
  })
  console.log(patient)
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<button data-id="1" id="showForm" class="btn">1</button>

<div id="conditionSelect">
  <h5>Form</h5>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="">Missing Tooth</label>
    <input type="text" id="missingVal">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="">Movement</label>
    <input type="text" id="movementVal">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="">Tilt</label>
    <input type="text" id="tiltVal">
  </div>
  <button id="saveCondition" onclick="saveConditions()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach. I've loaded your default form into a template which you can loop over. This means you don't have to hardcode each form directly into the page. I've then added one button which when clicked calls the `saveConditions` function. This loops over the forms extracting their data and adding it to the data object using a patient id.

```js
const patientCount = 3;
const data = {};

function getFormHTML(id) {
  return (
    `<div class="conditionSelect" data-id="patient${id}">
      <h5>Form</h5>
      <div class="field">
        <label>Missing Tooth</label>
        <input type="text" name="missingVal">
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label>Movement</label>
        <input type="text" name="movementVal">
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label>Tilt</label>
        <input type="text" name="tiltVal">
      </div>
    </div>`
  )
}

const html = [];
for (let i = 0; i < patientCount; i++) {
  html.push(getFormHTML(i));
}

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html.join(''));
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<button class="saveCondition">Save</button>')

const button = document.querySelector('.saveCondition');
button.addEventListener('click', saveConditions, false);

function getVal(form, name) {
  return form.querySelector(`[name=${name}]`).value
}

function saveConditions(e) {
  const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.conditionSelect');
  forms.forEach(form => {
    const patientId = form.dataset.id;
    data[patientId] = {
      missing: getVal(form, 'missingVal'),
      movement: getVal(form, 'movementVal'),
      tilt: getVal(form, 'tiltVal'),
    };
  });
  console.log(data);
}
```